# Resize Contents of TableViewCell based on Data pulled from API

Tags: ios, api, layout, uitableview

**I'm trying to get the cell to resize based on the contents that are getting pulled in from an API (image+text).**

I have it set right now that I leave space for an Image, a Headline (two lines), and a Description (two lines).

**The problem:** Sometimes no Image is available, sometimes the Headline is only one line, and sometimes there is no description or 1 line of description; *so I need to resize the cell based on these dynamic contents.*

**WebListCell.m**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(1, 20, 320, 180);
    self.headlineLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 210, 290, 40);
    self.descriptionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 250, 290, 30);

    [self.headlineLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
    [self.headlineLabel sizeToFit];
    [self.descriptionLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
    [self.descriptionLabel sizeToFit];
}
```

**WebListViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    Feed *feedLocal = [headlinesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *headlineText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", feedLocal.headline];
    NSString *descriptionText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", feedLocal.description];
    cell.headlineLabel.text = headlineText;
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = descriptionText;
    }

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    WebListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WebListCell"];
    Feed *feedLocal = [headlinesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *head = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", feedLocal.headline];
    cell.headlineLabel.text = head;
    if (head.length > 100 ){
        [cell.headlineLabel setNumberOfLines:1];
    }
} // WARNING ALERT: "CONTROL REACHES END OF NON-VOID FUNCTION"
```

I have `WebListCell.m` that lays out the cell, and then `WebListViewController.m` that calls `WebListCell.m` for the layout.  I'm pulling in all of the data correctly, but just **need help resizing and can't figure it out**, even though I've checked out other questions on StackOverflow... can anyone help with this?

*Right now what I have doesn't work to resize the cell height.*

Much appreciated, and I will post any additional code as needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` expects you to return a float value.. i.e. the height for the cell.  That's the exception being raised.

To figure out how much vertical space a string occupies, you can use this method:

```
CGSize size = [feedLocal.headline sizeWithFont:FONT 
                                      forWidth:WIDTH 
                                 lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

return size.height + SOME_PADDING;
```

You'll need to experiment with what width and padding looks good. You have some other variables that you mention in the question, but generally, this is what you'll need to do.